# search in list efficiency way (nested lis)

Tags: python, list, performance, nested, big-o

I have a nested list with 514000 list.
I have to find duplicated list and store their position.
I wrote a code, but with bad efficiency way.514000*514000  
Do you have a goold solution with good efficiency way ?
my nested list:

```
[["src_ip","src_port","dst_ip","dst_port"],["src_ip","src_port","dst_ip","dst_port"],
and so on
]
```

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question.

Comment: What does your nested list look like? Are all the 514000 are of a similar datatype?

Comment: Could you provide a sample input~?

Comment: some of them are duplicated. I have to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much faster solution is to use a `set` to track the items already seen so far and add the location of the duplicates to a list. Because lists are not hashable, they can be converted to a tuple. Here is the resulting code:

```py
seen = set()  # Unique items
result = []   # List of duplicate positions
for pos, item in enumerate(lst):
    tmp = tuple(item)
    if tmp in seen:
        result.append(pos)
    else:
        seen.add(tmp)
```

If you want to track where is the unique item associated to the duplicates found, you can just change `seen` to a `dict` and change `seen.add(tmp)` to `seen[tmp] = pos`. The resulting solution runs in linear time (ie. `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the input `lst`). This code takes about 250 ms on my machine with a list containing 514000 sub-lists of 4 short random strings.

Comment: Thak you man....

Comment: I know number of repeated of each duplicated item. Do you have any solution? It means if a list repeated 3 time, It return 3 for the given item.

Comment: In that case you need to count the number of item seen in the `else` part. You can change the `seen` variable to a `dict` (even a `defaultdict`) so the associated value count the items. Then you need to finally iterate over the `seen` dict to find the ones counted 3 times.